# Crash randomly when switching to Wireframe mode

Tags: edit-mode, wireframe, object-mode

I would like to know why do I randomly get a crash when I switch the display mode to wireframe on any file?

I tried to disable some of the add-ons but it still persists

Comment: Since you haven't given any details of the version of Blender you're using, what operation system you're running and whaether you've checked that you have the latest GPU drivers installed it's impossible to guess.

Comment: I'm using the version 3.3.1 on windows but how do I check about the drivers?

Comment: Go to the web site of the graphics card or of your computer if it has integrated graphics and check there. Blender [3.3.11](https://www.blender.org/download/lts/3-3/) is the latest version of 3.3 LTS so it might be worth downloading that in case a bug has been fixed since your version.